# How to read emails via Python from Gmail inbox account that has delegation rights for my account

Tags: gmail-api

I have to read emails and their attachment files from Inbox that has delegation rights for my account. Considering I don't have any credentials of delegated account

I don't find out any pythonic way to achieve this. From official documentations I was able to read my emails which are available in my inbox, but not from that delegated account inbox.

Comment: Your question doesnt make any sence want to try again maybe add some code